# Threads: BeginInvoke howto add a complete ListviewItem?

Tags: c#, winforms, multithreading, listviewitem

how can i add listview subitems through the BeginInvoke -> myDelegate process ? 
I've tried various versions of solutions, but allways with error!

thanks a lot for help!

```
    public delegate ListViewItem myDelegate(string  aItem);    
...
        if (InvokeRequired)
            {
            ListViewItem lvwItem = new ListViewItem();
            lvwItem.Text = strMessage;
            lvwItem.SubItems.Add(".2.");
            BeginInvoke(new myDelegate(listView1.Items.Add), new string[] { strMessage }); //works with a var of type string, but not for more Subitems.add()

            }
```

i found the answer, but i can't post it as answer because i have to wait up 7 hours....

i found the solution without crashing my multithreaded app... i'm stupid ;)

in my delegate i had used String instead of Listviewitem!

```
      public delegate ListViewItem myDelegate2(ListViewItem  aItem);
...
                                  if (InvokeRequired)
                                    {
                                        //BeginInvoke(new myDelegate(listView1.Items.Add), new object[] { strMessage });
                                        ListViewItem lvwItem = new ListViewItem();
                                        lvwItem.Text = strMessage;
                                        lvwItem.SubItems.Add(".2.");
                                        BeginInvoke(new myDelegate2(listView1.Items.Add), new object[] { lvwItem });
}
```

Comment: what the hell, if i edit my Question the answers will be deleted... strange!

Comment: No, I was correcting a couple of bugs in it so I temporarily deleted it until the code compiled properly!

Comment: nice to know... i had seen the message on the top of the browser, while i was editing my problem...

Answer (score 4):

You do seem to be getting rather tied up. Try this:

```
ListViewItem lvwItem = new ListViewItem();
lvwItem.Text = strMessage;
lvwItem.SubItems.Add(".2.");
if (listView1.InvokeRequired)
    listView1.BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(() => listView1.Items.Add(lvwItem)));
else
    listView1.Items.Add(lvwItem);
```

Comment: Your approach does not have static type checking which is why finding the error was harder than it should have been.